# Quicken passworded file import in quickboks

Tags: passwords, finance, quickbooks, quicken

I am trying to import some quicken files into quickbooks. The files have a password on them. Is there a way to do this import or get the password off the quicken file? I do have the password, I just dont have Quicken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access this data by downloading a quicken trial